# Angular $index ng-repeat CLOSED

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an array with: [petra, petrita, martin, jose]
and in my `ng-repeat` I show something like:

```
Petra with Img 0
Martin with Img 1
Jose with Img 2
Petra with Img 3
Jose with Img 4
Petrita wih Img 5
```

but, when i use a function with $index
the function return the position in the array for example:

```
when i click petra with img 0, return petra
when i click martin with img1, return petrita
when i click jose with img2,  return martin
when i click petra with img3, return jose
when i click jose with img4, return undefined
etc etc
```

when i click in someone i wanna have the name, when i click martin with img 1 i need the function return martin and not petrita.
what is the problem?

Codes:

```
    $scope.thisUser = function(index){
          share.setUseract($scope.users[index]);
          console.log(share.getUseract());  
        }
      }
     //in my custom service i have something like:
     setUseract: function(data){
       usuario = data;
     },
     getUseract: function(){
       return usuario;
     }
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8 margentop" ng-repeat="user in users"><span class="nombreimg"><a href="" ng-click="thisUser($index)">{{user}}</a></span></div>
```

Comment: Please add the ng-repeat you are using to your HTML.

Comment: Where is the ng-repeat?

Comment: You can pass `user` directly into `ng-click`: `ng-click="thisUser(user)"`

Comment: Head is spinning.. why `[petra, petrita, martin, jose]` has 4 elements, while ngRepeat shows 6? do you have 2 arrays out there? can you please provide full example somewhere in Plunker?

Comment: @sbedulin its because i have a json and the ng-repeat is more hard, i filter any photos of somebody by the date the photo was created, but the simple example was this.. I fix the problem thanks you brother

Answer (score 0):

You can try a swirch case to get the image once you have the index:
    var name;
    switch($index) {
        case 0 :
        case 3:
            name = 'Petra'
            break;
        case 2:
        case 4:
            name = 'Jose'
            break;
        ...
    }

```
return name
```